# How to pass credentials to PHP script after logging in Apache

Tags: php, forms, apache, .htaccess, session

I'm trying to set up a php script which needs to get credentials that user has passed on login form. I have already set up form authentication on my apache server with login form which redirects user to php script but when I access "session" cookie I get a long encrypted line rather than separate records for username and password. Is there a way to make apache to pass these values to php script? And if there is, how I can access those values?

Please see details below:

**.htaccess** for directory where php script is - webi/.htaccess:

```
AuthFormProvider ldap
AuthType form
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://my.server.addr/webi/login/index.html"
AuthName "LDAP"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.server.ip/ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
Require valid-user
Session On
SessionEnv On
SessionCookieName session path=/
SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
SessionMaxAge 900
```

**php script** - webi/profile/index.php:

```
    <?php
        $cookie_name = "session";
        if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
        {
            echo "<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]</span></a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'><span>Update profile data</span></a></li>";
            echo "<li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>";
            echo "<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<li class='active'><a href='#'><span>NO PROFILE</span></a></li>";
        }
    ?>
```

**login form** - webi/login/index.html:

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action="login-handler">
        <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" name="login" id="login-button">Login</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="httpd_location" value="http://my.server.addr/webi/profile" />
</form>
```

**.htaccess** for directory where login form is - webi/login/htaccess:

```
Require all granted
```

**.htaccess** for login-handler directory - webi/login/login-handler/.htaccess

```
SetHandler form-login-handler
AuthFormProvider ldap
AuthType form
AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://my.server.addr/webi/login/index.html"
AuthName "LDAP"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.server.ip/ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
Require valid-user
Session On
SessionEnv On
SessionCookieName session path=/
SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
SessionMaxAge 900
```

Thanks)

Comment: You are submitting the username and password using POST you should user `$_POST`. Session cookie contains a hash value (session-id)to identify the user connection to server. All session variables are (linked to session-id) stored on the server not  client (browser/cookie).

Comment: $_POST is set, but is empty. Is there any other way to get credentials passed to form-login-handler?

Comment: php `$_POST` is the recommended way to get form attributes of a HTTP POST request. If `$_POST` is empty as you say then there might be some other issue (may be ajax sysntax etc) which is causing the bad ly formed request. You should be looking how you can make `$_POST` to work instead of alternatives.

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with .htaccess in login-handler directory, but I just can't put my finger on it. Maybe I need to add some other directive to specifically instruct Apache to pass login credentials to requested location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial solution for this issue. One can use _SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] to access username passed through login form authentication.

I'm still however unable to access password.

Thanks to this post - http://software.danielwatrous.com/access-apache-ldap-authentication-details-in-php/